# SQL: Split string by delimiter multiple times into new columns

Tags: sql, string, split

I have ids and corresponding strings like this:

```
id    place
234   USA_NY_Buffalo
```

I want to split up the place string into three strings each with its own column:

```
id    Country  State  City
234   USA      NY     Buffalo
```

When I try splitting the string like this:

```
SELECT id, SPLIT(place,"_") FROM mytable
```

I get

```
id    place
234   USA
234   NY
234   Buffalo
```

Is it possible to split the string by the first "_", then split the second string again by " _ " ?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If the string would always have Country,State and City only then you could try something like.

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('USA_NY_Buffalo', '_', 1) AS country,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('USA_NY_Buffalo', '_', 2), '_', -1) AS State,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('USA_NY_Buffalo', '_', 3), '_', -1) AS City;
```